Would replacing "Be" or "Bee" with a bee graphic avoid trademark infringement
If I replace one word within a trademarked phrase with a graphic symbol (i.e. replacing the "Be" or "Bee" in phrases like Be Smart or Bee Smart with a Bee graphic) is it still trademark infringement?

Depends on where you are and what you do exactly. If you plan to do it, budget for professional legal advice applicable to your jurisdiction. Trademark protection protects consumers as well as trademark holders, and causing possible confusion among the products is bad.

Short Answer
It is impossible to say, in the abstract, if a change like replacing "be" or "bee" with a  "bee graphic" would or wouldn't be infringing, because the inquiry is decided on a case by case basis in a highly detailed fact specific way.
A good rule of thumb is that if you feel the need to ask, your mark is, at a minimum, in a gray area and might be infringing. So, you need to either consult a lawyer for a more fact specific inquiry, or change your mark.
Long Answer
Whether a mark infringes an existing trademark is evaluated on a case by case basis by the judge or jury who is the tier of fact in the case based upon all of the evidence presented at a trademark infringement trial (e.g. surveys and focus group tests and other expert testimony).
The basic standard for trademark infringement, assuming that the original trademark is valid, and that the competing mark is in the same market and geographic territory as the original mark, is whether the competing mark is confusingly similar to a consumer. The U.S. Patent and Trademark Office explains this likelihood of confusion standard here which explains that:

Trademarks don’t have to be identical to be confusingly similar.
Instead, they could just be similar in sound, appearance, or meaning,
or could create a similar commercial impression. Here are examples of
trademarks that were found to be confusingly similar.
Sound
These trademarks are confusingly similar because they could be
pronounced the same way, even though they’re spelled differently.



Appearance
These trademarks are confusingly similar in appearance, even though
the one on the left uses standard characters and the one on the right
uses a stylized font. Using standard characters protects the wording
itself, regardless of how it is displayed.



Commercial impression
These trademarks are confusingly similar because they convey the same
overall visual commercial impression. This is because they include the
same dominant design element, even though one includes words with the
design.



Related goods and services
Even if we determine that two trademarks are confusingly similar,
determining whether there is a likelihood between them also depends on
whether the goods or services associated with each trademark are
related. This is how identical trademarks with different owners can be
registered for Dove soap and Dove ice cream bars, or Delta faucets and
Delta air transportation services. Here are examples of goods or
services that were found to be related.
Goods
Your goods -- T-shirts and pants
Related goods -- Hats
Services
Your services -- Banking services
Related services -- Mortgage lending
services
Goods and services
Your goods -- T-shirts and pants
Related services -- Online retail
store services featuring clothing
Goods or services could be related if they are identical, similar or
competitive; used together; used by the same purchasers; advertised
together; or sold by the same manufacturer or dealer. If you’re not
sure how to identify related goods or services, here are a few
questions to help get you started:

The U.S. PTO website at the link above continues by providing some questions to ask yourself about your particular case.

When a consumer knows what goods or services you offer, what other
goods or services might they reasonably expect you to offer?
For example, if you sell hot dog buns, a consumer may expect you to
sell hamburger buns and loaves of bread.
What other types of goods or services do your competitors typically
provide?
For example, you provide pressure washing services and many of your
competitors also offer lawn mowing services in addition to pressure
washing services.
In a department store, what products might be displayed in the same
aisle as yours?
For example, you sell table lamps, which are commonly displayed near
decorative mirrors.
What other products are commonly used with yours?
For example, peanut butter and jelly, bread and butter, shoes and
socks.
What other goods or services are typically advertised with
yours?
For example, barbecue grills and bags of charcoal. Your answers will
result in goods and services that travel in “similar channels of
trade,” which means that they are related to yours.

There can be easy cases where the marks are so dissimilar that no reasonable person could possible confuse them. For example, no reasonable person could confuse the Nike Swoosh: 
with the Target retail store logo:
.
But, the gray area where a reasonable trier of fact could go either way is large.

For further reading, one might want to look up what a "Famous Mark" is. Think "Coca Cola", the "Nike Swoosh" or the bitten-off "Apple".
